# Why "default" in C# TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);

Tags: c#, sockets, default

I found some code on how to write a TCP/IP client-server app in C# 
The server Main starts with this:

```
TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);
int requestCount = 0;
TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
serverSocket.Start();
Console.WriteLine(" >> Server Started");
clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
```

Unfortunately I have no idea as to what the keyword **default** is doing in the third line. I would have thought that the last line initialises clientSocket, so there would be no need to initialise it before.

Comment: Note that this assignment doesn't do anything in this code fragment. The value (null) will be overwritten by the last line.

Answer (score 9):

`default` keyword is just setting the object `clientSocket` to `null` or default value of a reference type, since `TcpClient` is a class, (a reference type). It is same as :

```
TcpClient clientSocket = null;
```

In short it returns the *default* value of any type specified. For example, in case of `int` it will return `0`. like:

```
int i = default(int); // i = 0
```

`default` is useful in generic code, where the type is unknown.

See: [default Keyword in Generic Code (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx)